# jQuery parseFloat not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parsefloat

all. I'm trying to change a string into a float so that it can be formatted as currency. Problem is, parseFloat keeps returning NaN. What am I missing? Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ttyqaqde/).

HTML:

```
<div class="value num">948572</div>
<div class="value num">34567</div>
<div class="value num"></div>
```

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.value.num').each(function() {
    if( $(this).is(':empty')) {
      $(this).text('$0.00');
    } else {
      var numValue = Number.parseFloat($(this), 10);
      $(this).text('$' + (numValue / 100).toFixed(2));
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get the text of an html element using jQuery use [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.value.num').each(function() {
    if( $(this).is(':empty')) {
      $(this).text('$0.00');
    } else {
      var numValue = Number.parseFloat($(this).text(), 10);
      $(this).text('$' + (numValue / 100).toFixed(2));
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

`$(this)` refers to the `.value.num` element. Change it to:

```
var numValue = Number.parseFloat($(this).text());
```

(Also, there is no second parameter to [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat))